# How can I plot Apache HTTPd status counts in Graphite without Statsd using Logstash?

Tags: logstash, graphite, metrics

I'd like to send Apache HTTPd log statistics, such as 200 status counts to Graphite/Carbon. Logstash looks ideal but all the examples I've seen use Statsd to act as the state counter.
This means spinning up a Statsd server (or enabling Statsd in Collectd 5.x).

Is there a way for Logstash to write counters directly to Graphite/carbon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the "metric" filter in logstash. In the default configuration, it will emit metric events every 5 seconds for a given field. By resetting the counter every 5 seconds, you can send the data straight to Graphite's carbon server for storing.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }

    # make sure response code is valid
    if [response] =~ /\d\d\d/ {
        metrics {
            # A counter field
            meter => "apache.response.%{host}.%{response}"
            add_tag => "metric"
            clear_interval => "5"
            flush_interval => "5"
        }
    }
}

output {
    #stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    graphite {
        fields_are_metrics => true
        # only send metrics collected in the filter
        include_metrics => ["^apache\.response\..*"]
        #host => "localhost"
        #port => "2003"
    }
}
```

Every 5 seconds, the following event is created:

```
{
    "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-05-26T11:38:15.510Z",
    "message" => "ip-10-0-0-148",
    "apache.response.ip-10-0-0-145.401.count" => 1,
    "apache.response.ip-10-0-0-145.401.rate_1m" => 0.0,
    "apache.response.ip-10-0-0-145.401.rate_5m" => 0.0,
    "apache.response.ip-10-0-0-145.401.rate_15m" => 0.0,
    "tags" => [
        [0] "metric"
    ]
}
```